# Laplace's Equation Technique Help

Tags: partial-differential-equations, solution-verification, systems-of-equations, harmonic-functions, boundary-value-problem

I am trying to use separation of variables to solve

> $\triangle u = 0,\ u(x,\ 0) = 10,\ u(x,\ 2) = 0,\ u(0,\ y) = 0,\ u(1,\ y) = 0$

Plugging $u = X(x)Y(y)$ into the PDE leads to $-\frac{\frac{\partial^2 X}{\partial x^2}}{X} = \frac{\frac{\partial^2 Y}{\partial y^2}}{Y} = \lambda$.  My solutions to the Sturm-Louiville problems are $X = Ae^{-\sqrt{-\lambda} x} + Be^{\sqrt{-\lambda} x}$ and $Y = Ce^{-\sqrt\lambda y} + De^{\sqrt\lambda y}$ (I have ruled out the $\lambda = 0$ case).  Thus I have $$u = (Ae^{-\sqrt{-\lambda} x} + Be^{\sqrt{-\lambda} x})(Ce^{-\sqrt\lambda y} + De^{\sqrt\lambda y})$$

Then I apply the boundary conditions $u(0,\ y) = 0$ and $u(1,\ y) = 0$, yielding the system $$\begin{cases}0 = (A + B)(Ce^{-\sqrt\lambda y} + De^{\sqrt\lambda y}) \\ 0 = (Ae^{-\sqrt{-\lambda}} + Be^{\sqrt{-\lambda}})(Ce^{-\sqrt\lambda y} + De^{\sqrt\lambda y})\end{cases}$$

Since this this must hold for all $y$, not just the special case where $(Ce^{-\sqrt\lambda y} + De^{\sqrt\lambda y}) = 0$, this has to entail that $$\begin{cases}0 = A + B \\ 0 = Ae^{-\sqrt{-\lambda}} + Be^{\sqrt{-\lambda}}\end{cases}$$

This system has the solution $A = -B, \lambda = n^2 \pi^2$, so $$u = (Be^{n\pi xi} - Be^{-n\pi xi})(Ce^{-n\pi y} + De^{n\pi y})$$

This looks like a good time to apply Euler's Formula.  Letting $B$ eat some constants that pop out, this simplifies to $$u = Bsin(n\pi x)(Ce^{-n\pi y} + De^{n\pi y})$$

Next I apply the boundary conditions $u(x,\ 0) = 10$ and $u(x,\ 2) = 0$, yielding the system $$\begin{cases}10 = Bsin(n\pi x)(C + D) \\ 0 = Bsin(n\pi x)(Ce^{-2n\pi} + De^{2n\pi})\end{cases}$$

I have ruled out the $B = 0$ case, so I can divide the second equation by $B$.  Also, since this this must hold for all $x$, not just the special case where $sin(n\pi x) = 0$, this has to entail that $$\begin{cases}10 = B(C + D) \\ 0 = Ce^{-2n\pi} + De^{2n\pi}\end{cases}$$

This system has the solution $C = \frac{10e^{4n\pi}}{Be^{4n\pi} - B}, D = \frac{10}{B - Be^{4n\pi}}$.  However, this produces the PDE solution $u = 0$ when plugged back into $u = Bsin(n\pi x)(Ce^{-n\pi y} + De^{n\pi y})$.

I see now how I can proceed using Fourier Series, but why am I only getting the trivial solution out of this method when I use what appears to be valid algebra instead?

Comment: there should be some cosine terms somewhere

Comment: @daw For this to be true, wouldn't we need $A = B$ instead of $A = -B$, since sine is a sum of two complex exponents of opposite sign, and cosine is the sum of two complex exponents of the same sign?

Comment: When you write $u=B \sin(n \pi x)(\cdots)$, you get one solution for every allowed value of $n$, each with it's own constant $B_n$, so your general solution should be $u=\sum\limits_n B_n \sin(n \pi x)(\cdots)$. After using the boundary condition $u(x,2)=0$ to eliminate (say) $C$, absorb $D$ into $B$. The $B_n$ are found by using the last condition $u(x,0)=10$ and Fourier's trick.

Comment: @Sal So, since the general solution at that point is already an infinite linear combination over the $n$'s, is the step of eliminating $C$ with the condition $u(x,\ 2) = 0$ also a Fourier Series problem?